# how to use lodash mapValues with typescript

Tags: typescript, lodash

I have a code like below:

```
  interface Item {
    hours: number,
    minutes: number,
  }

  interface DataPoint {
    length: number,
    conversation: {
      a: number,
      b: number,
      [key: string]: number,
    }
  }

  interface DecoratedDataPoint {
    length: Item,
    conversation: {
      a: Item,
      b: Item,
      [key: string]: Item,
    }
  }
```

and I have a functions like below that makes use of lodash `mapValues` function

```
  function dataPointItem(val: number, total: number): Item {
    return {
      hours: Math.floor(val/60),
      minutes: val%60,
      percentage: Math.round((val/total)*100),
    }
  }

  function decorateDataPoint(dataPoint: DataPoint, total: number): DecoratedDataPoint {
    return {
      length: dataPointItem(dataPoint.length, number)
      conversation: _.mapValues(dataPoint.conversation, _.partialRight(dataPointItem, total))
    }
  }
```

what I expect to achieve is to assign computed `Item` values to `a` and `b` keys from `conversation` from `DecoratedDataPoint` type.

This code however doesn't work and  I'm getting an error:

```
  Type 'Dictionary<Item>' is not assignable to type '{ a: Item; b: Item; }'.
    Property ‘a’ is missing in type 'Dictionary<Item>'.
```

I've checked the result of `_.mapValues(....)` call and it returns properly structured object that adheres to how `Item` looks like.

Any ideas of what in this code is wrong?